# scanf mostra número sempre como par

Tags: c, c++

Estou com um problema e não sei como resolver pelo motivo de estar começando a utilizar o Dev-C++ agora. Não sei muito sobre ele, o problema é o seguinte eu consegui solucionar um erro que estava tendo, que era o uso da `%`. Agora estou com outro problema: qualquer número que eu digite vai aparecer na tela que é par. Alguém poderia por favor me informar em que linha eu errei e o erro que cometi?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    int N;
    printf ("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%f", &N);
    if (N<0)
        printf ("Este número não é positivo\n");
    if(N % 2 == 0)
        printf ("Este numero e par\n");
    else
        printf("Este número é impar");
    system ("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variável `N` é do tipo inteiro.
Mas, na sua chamada de `scanf` está usando `"%f"` que é para `float`.
Mude para `"%d"` (usado para inteiros decimais) que a leitura será feita corretamente.

Dê uma lida sobre `scanf` e `prinf` também, vai ajudar.

Veja em execução no [ideone](http://ideone.com/kiaD7R).

Answer (score 0):

Tomei a liberdade de fazer algumas modificações, procurei alterar o mínimo possível do seu programinha, primeiramente o "%d" do seu scanf, você estava usando "%f" que serve para float, outra coisa que também utilizei foi a modificação da condição do segundo if, que passou a comparar se o resto da divisão é (!=) diferente de zero(passando então a ser para números ímpares e o else para os pares), também utilizei a biblioteca de tradução, para habilitar os caracteres especiais do nosso idioma. Acho que isso resolveria seu problema. Deixo um conselho, seria bom usar as chaves nos if, else if e else, para evitar pequenas confusões, indentação e organização ajudam bastante para o entendimento e execução do programa.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main (){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int N;
    printf ("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    if (N<0)
            printf ("Este número não é positivo\n\n");
    if(N%2!=0)
        printf ("Este numero e ímpar\n\n");
    else
        printf("Este número é par\n\n");
    system ("PAUSE");
}
```